# Manager is trying to force me to communicate

Tags: communication, colleagues, manager

I am an apprentice at a company that shares office space with a *totally* different company (same CEO for both though).

I am only one of the two people (me and my manager) of my company working there, but I share office space with an employee of the other company.

Seeing that I am not that comfortable socializing and communicating in the office as a whole (I have *fixed* those issues when it implies communication with my manager, and communication flows fine with them), I received an email from my manager *asking*, quite firmly, that I communicate more with the employee that is with me in my room.

Although I can see the benefit that I would get more comfortable communicating, I don't want to do so. I don't see the interest, from my point of view, my state of mind and my work, to communicate in this situation, especially when *forced* and where there is nothing really to talk about with them.

How to respond to my manager professionally that I find the request quite *bizarre* (it is clearly not worded as an advice but as an order and can also be interpreted as a warning) and that I am not comfortable in doing so, despite what they ask?

Comment: I don't see what's so bizarre about this request. Expecting you to able to communicate with co-workers seems perfectly normal (to be clear, even if you're not working at the same company, working in the same room means they are a type of co-worker).

Comment: Not that bizarre at all. The employee may have complained about feeling isolated, and the CEO may want everyone to be a bit more chummy.

Comment: communicate or socialize?

Comment: You fixed your communication issues with your manager; can you have a similar conversation (or however you did it) about this issue?

Comment: Would you tell us what kind of communication is expected?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel why do you think forcing someone to talk with an employee from a different company isn't bizarre? It is really strange IMHO

Comment: @PiotrGolacki In what world is it bizarre to expect common courtesy, acknowledgement and a basic form of communication with people who you share an office with?!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel bizarre is forcing someone to do it. Even though there is no business reason to do it. Would you like to be forced to talk to someone you don't want to and don't need to? Forced is the key word here. Not encouraged, but forced.

Comment: @PiotrGolacki There is no business reason? I'd think that being able to communicate with your peers, colleagues, co-workers and customers is absolutely normal. If you're unable to even communicate and interact with someone you work in the same room daily, how are you going to fare in other interactions? There is definitely a business reason, businesses work because of communication.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel did you miss that the person is from different company and my impression is that communication is not really relevant for the OP work? It is as if you were forced to socialise with someone just because you share some office space. I think we talk about completely different things here.

Comment: @PiotrGolacki I didn't miss that, but they are still co-workers, as they are working in the same room, which is something that you seem to miss. If I had an employee that doesn't interact with other people  in their office at all (because that is what I think the concern is here), but just ignores them entirely, then I'd be very worried and urge them to try and communicate. Also, urging someone to communicate is on a far more basic level than requiring people to socialize.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But forcing and ordering someone to do it isn't normal, is it?

Comment: @PiotrGolacki _"asking, quite firmly,"_ is not ordering, nor forcing. The OP is an apprentice, which means that they are not just learning a job, but also learning how to interact in a business environment. Their manager is trying to learn them something. This is part of that learning. That said, I think ordering someone to communicate in a situation like described is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so how to interpret this: "it is clearly not worded as an advice but as an order and can also be interpreted as a warning" ?

Comment: @PiotrGolacki 1) That is the OPs interpretation, and 2) as I said, even if it is an order, it seems perfectly acceptable to me to do so, as this is a learning situation, and the OP seems to be actively ignoring people, which needs to be addressed for the OP to succeed (in general, or at least at this company).

Comment: A lot of ableist takes here. Has anyone considered the neurodivergent community who literally burn out by masking while talking with people. Yes I'll talk with the people around me more, but you'll get far less work done and it will take me personally a lot of time to recover at the end of the day. That is NOT something I would want to encourage. Let people communicate as much as they see fit as long as it does not interfere with work. Is it really that difficult to understand? Apparently so going by these comments

Comment: If you really can't cope with people, and your job requires you to do so, you may be in the wrong job. That isn't anyone's fault if so; it just means that if you aren't able to change you need to find a job that doesn't need those skills. Back room at post office worked for one person I know; it isn't exciting but he can be as much of an anonymous cog as he likes and he will rarely be asked to be otherwise. But not all professions are compatible with that much isolation, and not all jobs in those professions are ... and it's the employer who defines the requirements.

Comment: @PiotrGolacki I used to work for a defense contractor on an Air Force base and it was VERY common to have people from multiple companies working on the same project or working on different projects in the same office. It is childish and rude to refuse to talk to people just because they work for a different company when you see them in the hall, at the watercooler, in the lunchroom, etc. on a daily basis. It is quite reasonable to expect people who share an office space to use basic social decorum. This young person starting their career is in for a LONG road if they don't fix their attitude.

Answer (score 30):

> I am an apprentice at my company

So you need to do as requested, at least minimally. You don't typically get to do things your way as an apprentice.

All you need to do is be polite. You don't have work in common so just the social niceties need to be observed. They're an important part of working.

My guess is that the other person was asked and mentioned that you're not polite, this is a flag to a manager that you may be someone who may not work well in a team or have a strange attitude. Pushing back when all you need to do is say Hello, how are you? etc,. just sets the flag on fire.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a perfect thing to learn as an apprentice. You'll need it in the future.

Comment: Sorry, but this seems like a very presumptuous take. Plenty of workplaces don't like introverts and I've experienced similar coercion in the past. The answer isn't just 'be more open and talk with the coworkers'. That creates an unhealthy expectation that is literally masking for other peoples comfort. I'm not going to burn out masking so you can feel better. Get exactly what complaints the manager has and address those. Addressing the concerns might be telling them to get used to not being chummy with one employee. As long as work related communication is unhindered we don't need to socialize

Comment: Could also go "malicious compliance" route if we are talking about "minimally" doing as requested. Talk with the other employee, but be weird about it. Talk about your severed doll head collection, or list every type of sandwich you've ever eaten. Be very polite about everything though.  I think that this answer was right that it was probably the employee that  mentioned you don't talk, and this would get them off your case quick. Worth a shot if your alternatives are don't comply at all or be mentally drained from social interactions with this person every day.

Answer (score 7):

Communicating with people is a normal part of business. I would suggest you change your attitude real quick and accept this fact. Being an apprentice and having an attitude of...

> I don't want to do so. I don't see the interest, from my point of view, my state of mind and my work, to communicate in this situation, especially when forced and where there is nothing really to talk about with them.

...is going to give you a loooong haul in the corporate world and make you of limited use to any company.

Answer (score 4):

The benefit is you get to keep your job.

Bosses get to make demands of employees.  Unless the demand is unlawful due to some labor law, the employee generally needs to meet the demand.  Frankly, whether or not the request is reasonable isn't part of the equation.  Employers who continually make unreasonable demands may find it difficult to retain employees.

Comment: Very true and in this case, the manager simply wants the apprentice to communicate. There are few requests that are more basic than normal human interaction.